# Typing object of functions with flowtype

Tags: flowtype

I understand that this is the type of an object, which keys are the two strings `'foo'` and `'bar'`, and the values two functions (although I find the syntax strange):

```
type Func0 = {
    foo(number) : number,
    bar(string) : string
};
```

for example:

```
const f: Func0 = {
    foo: x => 2*x,
    bar: x => `hello ${x}`
};
```

But what is this type? The type of an object with two functions as values? If so, what are the keys?

```
type Func1 = {
    (number) : number,
    (string) : string
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a [callable object](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1969)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the callable object with two possible **strict outcomes**. Repro example here - [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UDeAoKUAUA7ArgWwCMIAnASgC4pdCSAaNTAZ2GIEssBzCqZtzlAL4oA9MKgB5ANJRgEZo3IoAxgHsszWAEYEmAGZZKMbtSLEEAPij6MAFgBMpZWo0w7OjPsPde7DhatYGADkABYQIEGOKKCQVu4mJFAAPjwsvqT+CWYpPvyiVgCGrAA2vjJywApO6sBW2ogeBlbG+Kb+1vaOqjVWbg2ezZS5fvCW1qHhkUA).

---

In brief,

```
type fn = {
  (number): number,
  (string): string
}
```

in pseudo-code is:

```
type fn =
  (number) => number
  OR
  (string) => string
```

so:

```
fn(number): number
fn(string): string
```

---

While with default function declaration you cannot **keep the relation between parameter type and return type**:

```
type fn = (number | string) => number | string
```

in pseudo-code is:

```
type fn = (number OR string) => number OR string
```

so:

```
fn(number): number | string
fn(string): number | string
```